# Airflow SFTPOperator keeps timing out before PUTting file

Tags: ssh, timeout, airflow, sftp

I have a DAG that downloads a file from GCS to local airflow temp folder

```
tmp_local_filepath="/usr/local/airflow/"+...
```

There's then an operator to send it to SFTP folder

```
sftp_transfer = SFTPOperator(
    dag=dag,
    task_id="file-copy-gsc-to-sftp",
    ssh_hook=SSHHook("sftp_conn"),
    local_filepath=tmp_local_filepath,
    remote_filepath=ftp_remote_filepath,
    operation="put",
    )
```

However it intermittently fails (about 50% of the time) due to timeout error.

```
Error while transferring None, error: [Errno 110] Connection timed out
```

I have tried:

- Changing the connection type between FTP and SSH
- Adding `{"timeout"="60"}` to the connection Extras to extend the time
- Adding it as an SSHHook as above - the DAG is migrated from an older stable system (pretty much intact) that directly used the Connection without creating a hook.

It's still timing out half the time, and I cannot figure out why, but this is a critical function I need to get stable.

We're running Airflow on Astronomer `v1.10.7+astro.11`

Any suggestions welcome at this point as I'm pulling my hair out! :)

Answer (score 0):

Turns out Astronomer added 3 new outgoing IP addresses in Jan 2021 - so these all need to be added to the receiving SFTP server whitelist, if they use whitelisting for security. Although this is only an issue for people using Airflow on Astronomer, hopefully it will prompt you to check for new IP addresses if you experience something similar with your SFTP operators.

- 35.245.140.149 (original IP address, still in use)
- 35.245.44.221
- 34.86.203.139
- 35.199.31.94

Source:
https://www.astronomer.io/docs/cloud/stable/manage-astronomer/vpc-access